# Change post date format for post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, format, printf

I would like some help with this. I would like to change the date format to numbers in my wordpress theme. Currently its set  February 5, 2014  to but I would like it to be like 02-05-14. I am not a php coder but I think it has something to do with the sprintf function that I copied from functions.php. The code below is from my functions.php file in my child theme.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <div class="featured-post">
        <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <header class="entry-header">

    <?php if ( is_search() || is_archive () || is_category () || is_tag () || is_home() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>


        <?php //if ( !(is_search() || is_archive() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_home()) ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php //endif; ?>

        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>

        <h1 class="entry-title  post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>


        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <!--<div class="comments-link">
                <?php // comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div>--><!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
        <footer class="entry-meta post-content">



        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        echo '<figure class="cat-thumb">';
        the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb');
        echo '</figure>';
        endif;
        ?>

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<div id="blogPostContent">'; }?>



                <p class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>"    rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

                <div class="entry-summary">


                <div class="postByLine">
                        <?php 
                    $date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
                    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                    esc_html( get_the_date() )
                    );

                    $author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
                            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
                            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ) ),
                            get_the_author()
                        );

                        echo ' Published on ' . $date . ' | By ' . $author . ' | ';


                    if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'No Comments', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Comment', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>

                        <?php endif; // comments_open()
                    ?>
                </div>


                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><span class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></span>

                </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

                <?php else : ?>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading  <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <?php endif; ?>


<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
echo '</div>'; } ?> <!-- end post content div -->



    </footer>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->



    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <? // php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
            <div class="author-info">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                <div class="author-description">
                    <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="author-link">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                            <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .author-link -->
                </div><!-- .author-description -->
            </div><!-- .author-info -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: I'm not providing a new answer as there are already two here that detail how to set the date format site wide. That is the preferred method since changing the theme's functions.php file is going to break when you update the theme (unless you create a child theme and override the desired function). Try changing the custom date format as detailed elsewhere in these answers. It should do what you're after and it should also make the change site wide and not just for this one field (since you REALLY don't want several date formats floating around your site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php the_time('d-m-y') ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Winmore but where in the code will i replace with your code ? I tried replacing the part directly under the class "postbyline" with it but it did not work.

Comment: I think i got it! I updated the code below and it works. thanks for your help! `<div class="postByLine">
<div class="thedate">Published on: <?php the_time('m-d-y'); ?></div>
       
       
 //the rest of the code here      
 echo ' | By ' . $author . ' | ';

      
`

Answer (score 4):

- Dashboard > Settings > General
- You can then choose the format you prefer:

[image]

- Select Custom and replace the textbox's content to `m-d-y`

Answer (score 2):

you can set your date formate from wp-admin settings>. General under date format.. change according to the date format check the image below[image: wp-admin general settings]

add m-d-Y on the custom filed to do it.